# Looking for a Cleaner Way To Make this Pagination Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to write a method that takes in an offset and limit along with a passed in Array of objects.  The objects always have an id column.  I want to return a new Array with the result based on the offset and limit. Here is an example, followed by my implementation that I'm not happy with (too many fences and fence post like variables which are always error prone). Also, if limit == -1 then take the rest.

Maybe there is a better way with slice?  Could reduce somehow help?

```
const baseArray = [{name: 'peter'},{name: 'terry'},{name: 'tammy'},{name: 'mary'}];
const offset = 1;
const limit = 2;
const speakerArray = getPaginatedData(baseArray,offset,limit);

speakerArray is [{name: 'terry',cursor: 'dGVycnk='},{name: 'tammy', cursor: 'dGFtbXk='];
```

where, the cursor's are calculated with this line of code:

```
console.log(Buffer.from('terry').toString("base64"));
```

Here is my implementation I don't like.

```
  const speakerArray = baseArray
    .filter((rec, index) => {
      return index > offset - 1 && (offset + limit > index || limit == -1);
    })
    .map((rec) => {
      rec.cursor = Buffer.from(rec.name.toString()).toString("base64");
      return rec;
    });
```

Comment: What's with the `cursor` stuff? It's not used for pagination here.

Comment: The cursor is part of the implementation I need. I didn't add it to the title of the post, but implied it in my example (graphql relay type stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the implementation with `slice` is

```
function getPaginatedData(array, offset, limit) {
  if(limit < 0) return array.slice(offset);
  return array.slice(offset, offset + limit);
}
const baseArray = [
  { name: "peter" },
  { name: "terry" },
  { name: "tammy" },
  { name: "mary" },
];
const offset = 1;
const limit = 2;
const speakerArray = getPaginatedData(baseArray, offset, limit);
```

Comment: That's pretty clean.  What about the adding of the cursor?

Comment: That you'd just `map` in (either with a copy or as you did assigning it in), but it's a different operation than paginating, isn't it?

Comment: True, I do need to add a cursor though that is dependent on id. Probably should have posted that as a separate question since it's not part of the paging

Comment: What is "id" here? Your original data doesn't have an "id" anyway.

Comment: Changed to rec.name from rec.id.  Oversight on my part simplifying original problem

Comment: Right. Well, that's a separate operation anyway. If you like, you could cache/memoize those transformations, though I'm not quite sure why you'd need a base64 cursor anyway, I'm pretty sure the GraphQL layer doesn't care.

Comment: Thanks @AKX, I'm really just simulating a cursor that might come down from a real graphql server and my point is to just make it opaque for teaching purposes.

Comment: In that case maybe hash it first, so you truly can't derive the original data from it.